# How to write SQL to display short date and time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, postgresql

I'm building a web application in asp.net using C# and postgreSQL database. The application is a booking system for appointments.

In a listbox I print the date, time and name of a certain appointment. I get get the date, time and name from the database.
My problem is that the date and time displays in long format, see picture below.

[image]

I want to display date in format **2014-04-22** and time in format **08:00**.

My code:

```
string sql = "SELECT date, time, name FROM tbl_app WHERE id = '" + id + "'";

NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    Listbox.Items.Add(dr["date"] + " " + dr["time"] + " " + dr["name"]);       
}
```

Comment: Use C# format strings - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ToShortDateString` and `ToShortTimeString` which work on strings, which is why I used `ToString` on the DataReader items

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    Listbox.Items.Add(dr["date"].ToString().ToShortDateString() + " " + dr["time"].ToString().ToShortTimeString() + " " + dr["name"]);       
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshorttimestring.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx

**Edit**
As the comment points out ToShortDateString does exist on Strings, instead it's applied to DateTime values... Code updated to show how

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    Listbox.Items.Add(
        DateTime.Parse(dr["date"].ToString()).ToShortDateString() + " " +
        DateTime.Parse(dr["time"].ToString()).ToShortTimeString() + " " + 
        dr["name"]);       
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but using ToShortDateString gives me an error: 'string' does not contain a definition for'ToShortDateString'

Comment: Thanks! That also works (the last code, under "Edit").

Answer (score 4):

Not really sure how the formatting could be done at Postgres end, but the fields appear to be of type `DateTime`, you can format the `DateTime` objects in your C# code like:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    //Check for DBNull.Value
    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["date"]);
    DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["time"]);
    Listbox.Items.Add(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " 
                      time.ToString("HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " 
                     + dr["name"]);
}
```

Consider using [parameter](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter.html) with  your Query instead of concatenating your query. This is prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You may see: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)